# Matlab using mesh to plot (Error using mesh (line 76) X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex)

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot this function but keep getting 'Error using mesh (line 76)
X, Y, Z, and C cannot be complex'. I found another question that suggested the use of abs on the sqrt function but this does not give the desired output. The output given should look like this[image]

```
function [ X,Y,Z] = plotComplexFunction(  )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

  x = linspace(-1,1);
  y = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);


  [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

  i = sqrt(-1);

  Z = exp(X+(i*Y));

  mesh(X,Y,Z)
end
```

Comment: The error tells you *exactly* what the problem is. Did you even read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the plot was made using only the real part of `Z`.
Changing the line where you call `mesh` to:

```
mesh(X,Y,real(Z));
```

produces this plot:

[image: Mesh plot of the real part of Z]